# User lacks privilege or object not found WITH JUnit

Tags: hibernate, junit

I'm having a problem when I use JUnit :

```
Hibernate: SELECT COUNT(0) FROM group
DEBUG - SqlExceptionHelper         - user lacks privilege or object not found: GROUP [n/a]
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: GROUP
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at $Proxy46.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:441)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:396)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:456)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:464)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:472)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:477)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForInt(JdbcTemplate.java:486)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.queryForInt(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.jdbc.SimpleJdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(SimpleJdbcTestUtils.java:56)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.countRowsInTable(AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests.java:115)
at fr.neosoft.neocommunity.dao.group.GroupTest.testSave(GroupTest.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: GROUP
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableName(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTableOrSubquery(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableReference(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadFromClause(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadTableExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQuerySpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryPrimary(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryTerm(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpressionBody(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadQueryExpression(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.compileCursorSpecification(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 50 more
WARN  - SqlExceptionHelper         - SQL Error: -5501, SQLState: 42501
ERROR - SqlExceptionHelper         - user lacks privilege or object not found: GROUP
```

This is only for one of my entities. Tests for the others are ok but not for this one.

I use Hibernate 4, JUnit 4, Spring 3 and JPA 2.

I you want to see my entity or anything else, I can post it.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GROUP is reserved word in HSQLDB, as told in [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/lists-app.html). Do not use reserved word as name for your table.

You can control name of table with [@Table](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Table.html) annotation:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="some_other_descriptive_name")
public class Group {
...
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to configure HSQLDB so that I can use "GROUP" as table name?